# rake db create aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, rubygems

I have been trying to fix my project using Ruby 2.3.8, I am using rvm to install Ruby 2.3.8 but need extra works to install that on my mac because `2.3.8` need can't resolve with `openssl 1.1`. So I need to find how to install `openssl 1.0` because Homebrew deleted the `openssl 1.0` so it needs extra research to fix that.

In my project I am using MySQL 5.7 and to install MySQL 5.7 I need to install OpenSSL 1.1 again, so it automatically installs OpenSSL 1.1

When I go to my project and doing `rake db:create`  I got error like this:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: library not found for class Digest::SHA1 -- digest/sha1
/Users/hoomacbuk/Documents/mekari/quickbook/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/hoomacbuk/Documents/mekari/quickbook/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/hoomacbuk/Documents/mekari/quickbook/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/hoomacbuk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/hoomacbuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18/digest/sha1.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/hoomacbuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18/digest/sha1.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/hoomacbuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18/digest/sha1.bundle
/Users/hoomacbuk/Documents/mekari/quickbook/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/hoomacbuk/Documents/mekari/quickbook/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/hoomacbuk/Documents/mekari/quickbook/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/hoomacbuk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
```

And when I running `bin/rake db:create` I got this error again :

```
/Users/hoomacbuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/digest.rb:16:in `const_missing': library not found for class Digest::SHA1 -- digest/sha1 (LoadError)
```

How can I get Ruby 2.3.x to run? I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with your ruby version.

Uninstall the current version and reinstall the same one and then try again.

```
rvm uninstall 2.3.8
```

and then

```
rvm install 2.3.8
```

Comment: i have been doing this many time and i cant do rvm install 2.3.8 only, must using openssl dir also, i have been doing this many time but not work

Comment: please post the exact error that you are receiving when you try to install ruby